# この工場は規模こそ小さいが、年商は数十億円に上がる。

Tags: grammar

> 問題１　この工場は規模こそ小さいが、年商は数十億円に上がる。
>
> １．こそ　２．だの　３．さえも　４．ですら

皆さん、どうしてこの文章にはこそを使いますか？

今日こそか、これこそとか
この場合は、ネガティブの意味だから、
こそはどういういみです？
どうして規模でされ使わないでしょうか？

> 問題２　たばこは健康に害を及ぼし_________、いい影響は与えない。
>
> １．兼ねて
> ２．こそすれ
> ３．次第で
> ４．ずくめで

この文章はどういう意味ですか。

それに、こそすれの使い道を教えてお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

「は」に置き換えても意味は大きく変わりません。「こそ」によって直前の語を強調しているだけです。

**問題1**

- この工場は規模**こそ**小さいが、年商は数十億円に上がる。
- この工場は規模**は**小さいが、年商は数十億円に上がる。

工場の規模が小さいにも関わらず年商が多いという対比が強調されています。

**問題2**

- たばこは健康に害を及ぼし**こそ**すれ、いい影響は与えない
- たばこは健康に害を及ぼし**は**すれど(も)、いい影響は与えない

害を及ぼしてばかりであることが強調されています。

**こそすれ**

「～こそすれ」は「～はするけれど」の「～」の部分（動作）を強調しつつ堅めに言い換えた表現です。

「すれ」というのは「すれど」「すれども」の「ど(も)」が省略された形です。
「するけど」の堅い言葉と捉えておけば良いでしょう。

次の三つはどれも似た意味であり、強調の度合いと表現の堅さが異なるだけです。

- うちの子はゲームこそすれ、勉強はしない。
- うちの子はゲームこそするが、勉強はしない。
- うちの子はゲームはするけれど、勉強はしない。

「～」の部分には名詞も使えますが、少し形が変わります、

- 緊急事態宣言こそ発令されど(も)、都市封鎖はされていない。
- 緊急事態宣言は発令されたが、都市封鎖はされていない。
- 彼は今でこそ優秀であれど、元は落ちこぼれであった。
- 彼は今では優秀だが、元は落ちこぼれだった。

Answer (score 1):

その2つの例文に使われている「こそ」は、

> こそ［係助］種々の語に付く。
>   ２ ある事柄を一応認めておいて、それに対立的、あるいは、否定的な事柄を続ける。
>   「感謝**こそすれ**、恨むことはあるまい」
>   「賛成**こそ**する**が**、積極的ではない」
>   [補説] 2は、現代語では、多く「こそあれ」「こそすれ」「こそするが」などの形で用いられる。
>   ([デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%93%E3%81%9D/#jn-79455))

および、

> こそ 〘副助〙
>   ❷《「…こそすれ」「…にこそなれ」「…こそ…だが」などの形で》物事を他から取り立てて、それと対比的な物事が否定されることを予測させる。…こそ…けれど。
>   「喜び**こそすれ**怒ったりはしない」
>   「男女の違い**こそあれ**二人はうりふたつだ」
>   「害に**こそなれ**薬にならない」
>   「物腰**こそ**[慇懃]{いんぎん}**だが**、根は腹黒い」
>   (明鏡国語辞典)

で説明されている用法です。問題１の、

> この工場は規模**こそ**小さい**が**、年商は数十億円に上がる。

は、「規模が小さい」ということを認めておいて、それに対立する「年商は数億円に上がる」という事柄を続けるものです。また問題２の、

> たばこは健康に害を及ぼし**こそすれ**、いい影響は与えない。

は、「たばこは健康に害を及ぼす」ということを認めたうえで、それとは対比的な「いい影響を与え...」ることを否定（「...ない」）するものです。