# Meaning of こそすれ

Tags: grammar, meaning, words

Could somebody tell me the meaning of こそすれ?

I've searched it on Google, but I still don't understand what does it mean or what function it has. Sometimes the meaning of こそすれ seems to be "to do only something", sometimes the meaning seems to be "to never do anything", and sometimes I simply don't know why こそすれ is used. I must say that I'm completely lost about the usage of this word.

Besides telling the meaning, if someone could give me some example sentences where the meaning can be fully noticed, I would be really thankful.

Comment: こそ is a word on it’s own. it emphasizes the word before it. それ is just “that”. give us more context where you found this and we can better help you parse the sentence.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76491/9831